# Netbeans printing character codes

Tags: java, netbeans, html-escape-characters

I am trying to print out html character codes e.g. &# 230; in the Netbeans Console but it recognises them as character codes and so tries to print them out.

Is there any way to print out the codes?

Thanks for the help

Comment: do you mean that you want to print out the character code literally (`&#230;`) or the character the code corresponds to (`æ`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know much about Netbeans but try `&amp;#230;`.

Comment: Thank you this fixed the problem!